# PDF Print Output is Blank

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I have created a Photoshop PDF in Photoshop.

The PDF can be sent to my desk printer but the printer only outputs a blank page.

My printer is a humble monochrome HP LaserJet P1102w.

I am saving the PDF with the following settings:

- Layers checkbox is **ticked** (unticking it does not help)
- Color checkboxes are unticked
- Adobe PDF Preset is [Smallest File Size] (Modified)
- Standard is None
- Compatibility is Acrobat 8 (PDF 1.7)

General:

- Preserve Photoshop Editing Capabilities is unticked
- Embed Page Thumbnails is unticked
- Optimize for Fast View Preview is **ticked**
- View PDF After Saving is unticked

Compression:

- Bicubic Downsampling To 100ppi from images above 150ppi
- Compression is JPEG
- Image Quality is Medium
- Convert 16 Bit/Channel Image to 8 Bits/Channel is **ticked**

Output:

- Color Conversion is Convert to Destination
- Destination is sRGB IEC61966-2.1
- No Profile Inclusion Policy

Passwords are not required

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. My printer is just a basic laser printer with only black toner.

Comment: Is there a reason why you first convert to PDF rather than just hitting <Ctrl>+<P> with the .psd file open?

Comment: The reason that I am saving the document as a PDF is so that I can send it to others. They may wish to print it so I was testing what it printed out like.

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using to print and view the PDF?  Have you tried Adobe Reader?  Solving this problem may be virtually impossible without access to the file.

Comment: @Vincent Why would you ever print directly from Photoshop?

Comment: There is no way to determine why you may be getting blank PDF prints. If the PDF shows the images/design, then the problem is between your PDF viewing software, the printer driver, and the printer. None of which can be solved here.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor why would you *not*? Photoshop itself is a software RIP when printing.. so there's no real benefit to going to a PDF first (which is also a software RIP).

Comment: @Ovaryraptor to print the work you did in that program, and when it's the only part of the CC you have access to.